# Segmentation fault with dialog

Tags: linux, bash, shell, segmentation-fault, dialog

I'm getting a segmentation fault with the following script when it's more that one child dir past the pwd. The program kills with the error message and I have to reset the shell.

For example: I start in `/` and run the script. I navigate to from `/` to `/etc` just fine. When I try to go to `/etc/httpd/` that's when I get the segment fault.

Another example: I start the script with `lsgui /etc` and at that point it will display that dir but when I try to navigate to another dir it faults again.

```
#!/bin/bash

output=${1-$PWD}
IFS=$'\r\n' lss=($(ls -1 $output))
for ((i=0;i<${#lss[@]};i++));do
x+=($i \"${lss[$i]}\")
done

justdir=($(basename $output))
desc=($(grep $justdir /root/lsgui.conf))
if [ -z $desc ]
then
desc=$output
fi

dialog --keep-tite --title 'lsgui' --menu $desc 40 70 ${#lss[@]} ${x[@]} 2>/tmp/lsgui.$$

if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
rm -f /tmp/lsgui.$$
clear
exit 0
fi

result=`cat /tmp/lsgui.$$`

case $? in
0)
  if [ -d ${lss[$result]} ];then
    /root/lsgui $output/${lss[$result]}
  else
    dialog --keep-tite --title "${lss[$result]}" --textbox $output/${lss[$result]} 40 70
  fi

esac
```

**UPDATE**

The problem was `if [ -d ${lss[$result]} ];then`. It was looking to open a file in a dir. This was fixed by changing the previous statement to `if [ -d $output/${lss[$result]} ];then`. I probably could have prevented the segfault in the first place by checking if the dialog textbox was a file or not.